# Reading values of variables from file using system calls

Tags: c, token, system-calls

I want to open a file named config.txt and read from it the value of some variables.

The file has this format:

```
K 10
C 5
E 20
```

The order of the variables can change.
I want to extract the values and store them into the corresponding variables using open, read, close system calls.

What I already wrote is:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200112L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PRINTUSAGE(x)                                           \
    {                                                               \
        fprintf(stderr, "use: %s config.txt\n", x);         \
        return EXIT_FAILURE;                                        \
    }

#define CHECK_EQ(name, X, val, str, ...)        \
        if ((X)==(val)) {                           \
            perror(#name);                          \
            int errno_copy = errno;                 \
            print_error(str, __VA_ARGS__);          \
            exit(errno_copy);                       \
        }

void print_error(const char *str, ...){
    const char err[]="ERROR: ";
    va_list argp;
    char * p=(char *)malloc(strlen(str)+strlen(err)+512);
    if (!p) {
        perror("malloc");
        fprintf(stderr,"FATAL ERROR nella funzione 'print_error'\n");
        return;
    }
    strcpy(p,err);
    strcpy(p+strlen(err), str);
    va_start(argp, str);
    vfprintf(stderr, p, argp);
    va_end(argp);
    free(p);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2)
        PRINTUSAGE(argv[0]);

    char *infile = argv[1];
    int fin, len;

    int K, C, E;

    CHECK_EQ(open, fin=open(infile, O_RDONLY), -1, "Opening file in input %s : errno=%d\n", infile, errno);

    //todo

    read_values(fin, *K, *C, *E);

    printf("K=%d C=%d E=%d\n", K, C, E);

    //endtodo

    CHECK_EQ(close, len=close(fin), -1, "Closing file in input %s : errno=%d\n", infile, errno);
    return 0;
}

int read_values(int fin, int *K, int *C, int *E){
    //todo
}
```

How can I implement the function?

Comment: Don't include every header under the sun in a simple program; use only the necessary headers.

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(p+strlen(err), str);`  this is a bad idea, suggest using: `strcat( p, str );`

Comment: regarding: `char * p=(char *)malloc(strlen(str)+strlen(err)+512);`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone) Suggest removing that cast.

Comment: regarding: `if (!p) {
        perror("malloc");
        fprintf(stderr,"FATAL ERROR nella funzione 'print_error'\n");
        return;
    }`  this is an unrecoverable error.  So rather than `return` suggest: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE ):`

Comment: regarding the function: `int read_values()`  this function is called before it is defined AND there is no prototype near the top of the file.  SO, at best, the compiler will assume where the function is called, that all parameters are `int`, that the returned type is `int`.  This is NEVER a good thing.  Suggest inserting a prototype for the function before the `main()` function

Comment: regarding; `read_values(fin, *K, *C, *E);`  What is needed is the addresses of the local variables NOT `*K`, etc.  Suggest: `read_values(fin, &K, &C, &E);`

Comment: How do you *think* you should implement the function? Tell us what you thought, and we can tell you if there's a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some issues in your code and your compiler probably tells you what.

This is could probably be one way to look at it.

```
int read_values(int fd, int *K, int *C, int *E) {

    int *v;
    size_t rb;
    char buf[1024];

    while ((rb = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)))) {
        char *i;    /* iterator */
        char *e;    /* end of buffer data */
        for (i = buf, e = buf + rb; i < e; i++) {
            if (isspace(*i))
                continue;
            if (*i == 'C')
                v = C;
            else if (*i == 'E')
                v = E;
            else if (*i == 'K')
                v = K;
            else
                return -1; /* parsing error, unknown value */
            *v = strtol(i + 1, &i, 10);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```